# Combine multiple ranges (not formatted tables) from one Excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

It sounds very easy but I looked for this similar question, but looks like I didn't find suitable. Mostly are slightly different issues then mine..

I am receiving monthly one big Excel file, where I got different sheets, but only on one sheet I am having 3x different data ranges (not formatted tables). I am saying it again, ranges not tables, because some "smart" collogues decided just to overwrite file with new data but just to expand the range...so it stayed as range (it goes horizontal), and not table. For Power Query is needed table format I know..

So my issue is to somehow consolidate those ranges (3 of them) on that one sheet into one Query, but without disrupting the original Excel file, and of course to make it dynamic when I am getting new files.

I am comfortable with Power Query, but I didn't have similar things like this where you have more ranges that have to be cleaned, edited and appended into one query...Positive thing is, the column names are the same, just the content are different...

[image]

As you can see the data range is in so called "blocks" on data that are going horizontally...

This is basically something what I would like to have:

[image]

If question already exists please link!

Here is my test file to check it up:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RDAoZqxKPk1NdhtcYec8nG_31PFwQ7Lj/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101738555398870704584&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: This is all very vague without stating what you have, what to expect could happen and what output is required with actual examples

Comment: @P.b I put a second SS...it is just appended table....I am more interested how to approach with that query where I have more ranges...

Comment: PowerQuery supports “connecting” to ranges from a sheet. Depending on how fixed the starting position of the 3 blocks/ranges are, you may want to use 1 or 3 queries to transform them into tables and then append them. So you may want to create 3 queries using your screenshot as source to extract column 1..4, 8..11, 16..19 to 3 tables or query results. Then use another query to append them. (Also possible to put all this in one (less “readable”) query)

Comment: @Anonymous okay.. i did it but I can’t refresh the data on Refresh all, I am not having new data. Have to go Query and Refresh Preview first then it works….

Comment: @Mirza not clear what you are referring to, as far as I remember it is possible to adjust the settings regarding the refreshing behavior e.g. when opening the file.  About “refresh all” I experience the same in some cases as well that it does not work, but never bother to fix. In your case you could keep first query as connection only and put the other 3 queries together into one. Then you just need to refresh the combined one (and the connection only query will refresh automatically with it).

Comment: @Anonymous  I see… but does it matter if the file is From Excel workbook direct or From Folder? Does it matter?

Comment: @Mirza I just started to google about this topic. There is one chat mentioning whether the source is currentWorkbook or Workbook. So you may want to give it a try and test your idea (but my understanding was that in your case the sheet comes from another xlsx file?) I run PQ mostly in PowerBI Desktop and Refresh All works here.

Comment: @Anonymous  Yes from Excel file… but it can be changed ofc.. but i wanna know if it matters

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by combining into 3x queries and then appended into one bigger table.
and, import From Folder is the best import, rather then direct from Excel Workbook, it gives me more space for adding the filter for instance "Date Created" so you can always have the newest on the top or whatever.

Thx anyways for some input of you guys.

Comment: So, Refresh-All works  properly as well?

Comment: @Anonymous Well yes, without problems it is refreshing all as it should be.